How to prove Bernstein's inequality?
I am currently learning the basics of machine learning and have come across Bernstein's inequality. This inequality is particularly useful in understanding the behavior of averages of random variables.
Consider $m$ i.i.d random variables $X_i, i \in [m]$. Let $\bar{X} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m} X_i}{m}$. If there exists a constant $b > 0$ such that for all $k \geq 2$, the $k$-th moment satisfies $\mathbb{E}[|X_i|^k] \leq \frac{k! b^{k-2}}{2} \mathbb{V}[X_1]$, then Bernstein's inequality states that:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\bar{X} \geq \mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] + \epsilon) \leq \exp\left(\frac{-m\epsilon^2}{2 \mathbb{V}[X_1] + 2b\epsilon}\right)
$$
This inequality provides a bound on the probability that the sample mean $\bar{X}$ deviates from its expected value by at least $\epsilon$, highlighting the relationship between the variance, the number of samples, and the deviation $\epsilon$.
However, I cannot find the complete proof on Wikipedia since it is omitted, and the original four papers mentioned are too old to be retrieved on Google Scholar.
Are there any related materials available? I searched StackExchange, but found only one relevant post, which has remained unanswered for over three years.
Thanks in advance for any help!

You can check some online lecture notes:
https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=sml/Concentration.pdf
https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~rebeschi/teaching/AFoL/22/material/lecture07.pdf
https://zcc1307.github.io/courses/csc588sp21/notes/0126.pdf

Ch 6 is here https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~rebeschi/teaching/AFoL/22/material/lecture06.pdf

Proof of Sub-Exponential Condition
Given:

Moment Condition:
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left[|X - \mathbb{E}[X]|^k\right] \leq \frac{k! \, b^{k-2}}{2} \, \mathbb{V}[X], \quad \forall k \geq 2
  $$

Objective:
Show that the moment condition implies the Sub-Exponential Condition:
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda (X - \mathbb{E}[X])}\right] \leq \exp\left(\frac{\mathbb{V}[X] \lambda^2}{2(1 - b\lambda)}\right), \quad \forall \lambda \in \left[0, \frac{1}{b}\right)
  $$



Step 1: Center the Random Variable
Let:
$$
Y = X - \mathbb{E}[X]
$$
Our goal is to bound the moment-generating function (MGF) of ( Y ):
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda Y}\right]
$$

Step 2: Expand the Exponential Moment
Expand the MGF as a power series:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda Y}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda Y)^k}{k!}\right] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \mathbb{E}[Y^k]
$$
Since ( \mathbb{E}[Y] = 0 ), the ( k = 1 ) term vanishes:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda Y}\right] = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \mathbb{E}[Y^k]
$$

Step 3: Bound Central Moments Using Moment Condition
From the moment condition:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[|Y|^k\right] \leq \frac{k! \, b^{k-2}}{2} \, \mathbb{V}[X]
$$
Thus:
$$
|\mathbb{E}[Y^k]| \leq \mathbb{E}\left[|Y|^k\right] \leq \frac{k! \, b^{k-2}}{2} \, \mathbb{V}[X]
$$

Step 4: Substitute into the MGF Expansion
Plug the bound into the MGF expansion:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda Y}\right] \leq 1 + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \cdot \frac{k! \, b^{k-2}}{2} \, \mathbb{V}[X] = 1 + \frac{\mathbb{V}[X]}{2} \sum_{k=2}^\infty (b\lambda)^{k-2} \lambda^2
$$
Simplify the sum by setting ( j = k - 2 ):
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda Y}\right] \leq 1 + \frac{\mathbb{V}[X] \lambda^2}{2} \sum_{j=0}^\infty (b\lambda)^j
$$

Step 5: Sum the Geometric Series
The geometric series converges for ( b\lambda < 1 ):
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty (b\lambda)^j = \frac{1}{1 - b\lambda}
$$
Thus:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda Y}\right] \leq 1 + \frac{\mathbb{V}[X] \lambda^2}{2(1 - b\lambda)}
$$

Step 6: Apply the Exponential Inequality
Use the inequality ( 1 + x \leq e^{x} ) for all real ( x ):
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda Y}\right] \leq \exp\left(\frac{\mathbb{V}[X] \lambda^2}{2(1 - b\lambda)}\right)
$$
This matches the Sub-Exponential Condition:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda Y}\right] \leq \exp\left(\frac{\mathbb{V}[X] \lambda^2}{2(1 - b\lambda)}\right), \quad \forall \lambda \in \left[0, \frac{1}{b}\right)
$$
This derivation confirms that the Moment Condition implies the Sub-Exponential Condition, enabling the application of concentration inequalities like Bernstein's Inequality.

Proof of Bernstein's Inequality
Statement:
Given ( m ) i.i.d random variables ( X_i ), ( i \in [m] ), and let ( \bar{X} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m} X_i ). If there exists a constant ( b > 0 ) such that for all ( k \geq 2 ),
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[|X_i - \mathbb{E}[X_i]|^k\right] \leq \frac{k! \, b^{k-2}}{2} \, \mathbb{V}[X_1],
$$
then for any ( \epsilon > 0 ),
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\bar{X} \geq \mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] + \epsilon\right) \leq \exp\left(\frac{-m\epsilon^2}{2 \mathbb{V}[X_1] + 2b\epsilon}\right)
$$

Step 1: Define the One-Sided Bernstein Condition
First, recall the One-Sided Bernstein Condition for a parameter ( b > 0 ):
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda(Y)}\right] \leq \exp\left(\frac{\mathbb{V}[Y] \lambda^2 / 2}{1 - b\lambda}\right), \quad \forall \lambda \in \left[0, \frac{1}{b}\right)
$$
where ( Y = X - \mathbb{E}[X] ).
From the Moment Condition, we have already established that ( Y ) satisfies the Sub-Exponential Condition:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda Y}\right] \leq \exp\left(\frac{\mathbb{V}[Y] \lambda^2}{2(1 - b\lambda)}\right), \quad \forall \lambda \in \left[0, \frac{1}{b}\right)
$$
Thus, ( Y ) satisfies the One-Sided Bernstein Condition with ( \mathbb{V}[Y] = \mathbb{V}[X] ).
Step 2: Apply the Chernoff Bound
Consider the sum of ( m ) i.i.d random variables ( Y_i = X_i - \mathbb{E}[X_i] ):
$$
S_m = \sum_{i=1}^{m} Y_i = m(\bar{X} - \mathbb{E}[\bar{X}])
$$
We aim to bound the probability ( \mathbb{P}(S_m \geq m\epsilon) ), which is equivalent to ( \mathbb{P}(\bar{X} \geq \mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] + \epsilon) ).
Using the Chernoff Bound:
$$
\mathbb{P}(S_m \geq m\epsilon) \leq \inf_{\lambda > 0} \exp(-\lambda m \epsilon) \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda S_m}\right]
$$
Step 3: Bound the MGF of the Sum
Since the ( Y_i ) are independent:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda S_m}\right] = \prod_{i=1}^{m} \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda Y_i}\right] \leq \left[\exp\left(\frac{\mathbb{V}[Y_i] \lambda^2}{2(1 - b\lambda)}\right)\right]^m = \exp\left(\frac{m \mathbb{V}[Y] \lambda^2}{2(1 - b\lambda)}\right)
$$
Thus:
$$
\mathbb{P}(S_m \geq m\epsilon) \leq \inf_{\lambda > 0} \exp\left(-\lambda m \epsilon + \frac{m \mathbb{V}[Y] \lambda^2}{2(1 - b\lambda)}\right)
$$
Step 4: Optimize the Bound Over ( \lambda )
To find the tightest bound, we optimize over ( \lambda ). The optimal ( \lambda ) minimizes the exponent:
$$
-\lambda m \epsilon + \frac{m \mathbb{V}[Y] \lambda^2}{2(1 - b\lambda)}
$$
Take the derivative with respect to ( \lambda ) and set it to zero:
$$
-\epsilon + \frac{\mathbb{V}[Y] \lambda}{1 - b\lambda} + \frac{\mathbb{V}[Y] \lambda^2 b}{2(1 - b\lambda)^2} = 0
$$
However, solving this equation directly is complex. Instead, we can choose:
$$
\lambda = \frac{\epsilon}{\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon}
$$
This choice of ( \lambda ) lies within ( \left[0, \frac{1}{b}\right) ) since:
$$
\lambda b = \frac{b\epsilon}{\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon} < 1
$$
Step 5: Substitute the Optimal ( \lambda ) Back Into the Bound
Substitute ( \lambda = \frac{\epsilon}{\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon} ) into the exponent:
$$
-\lambda m \epsilon + \frac{m \mathbb{V}[Y] \lambda^2}{2(1 - b\lambda)} = -\frac{m \epsilon^2}{\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon} + \frac{m \mathbb{V}[Y] \left(\frac{\epsilon}{\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon}\right)^2}{2\left(1 - \frac{b\epsilon}{\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon}\right)}
$$
Simplify the denominator in the second term:
$$
1 - b\lambda = 1 - \frac{b\epsilon}{\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon} = \frac{\mathbb{V}[Y]}{\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon}
$$
Now, substitute back:
$$
-\frac{m \epsilon^2}{\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon} + \frac{m \mathbb{V}[Y] \left(\frac{\epsilon}{\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon}\right)^2}{2\left(\frac{\mathbb{V}[Y]}{\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon}\right)} = -\frac{m \epsilon^2}{\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon} + \frac{m \epsilon^2}{2(\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon)} = -\frac{m \epsilon^2}{2(\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon)}
$$
Thus:
$$
\mathbb{P}(S_m \geq m\epsilon) \leq \exp\left(-\frac{m \epsilon^2}{2(\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon)}\right)
$$
Step 6: Relate Back to the Sample Mean
Recall that:
$$
S_m = m(\bar{X} - \mathbb{E}[\bar{X}])
$$
Therefore:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\bar{X} - \mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] \geq \epsilon\right) = \mathbb{P}(S_m \geq m\epsilon) \leq \exp\left(-\frac{m \epsilon^2}{2(\mathbb{V}[Y] + b\epsilon)}\right)
$$
Since ( \mathbb{V}[Y] = \mathbb{V}[X] ), we have:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\bar{X} \geq \mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] + \epsilon\right) \leq \exp\left(-\frac{m \epsilon^2}{2(\mathbb{V}[X] + b\epsilon)}\right)
$$
This completes the proof of Bernstein's Inequality under the given moment condition.
